# How to redirect www.example.com to example.com in NginX?

Tags: redirect, nginx

When we open `example.com` (without HTTPS), the site loaded very well but when we open `www.example.com` (without HTTPS) it opens "Welcome of nginX" but I do not need this, we want to open `example.com` even if the URL is `www.example.com`.

NOTE: our site has "HTTPS" and when we open `example.com`, it will be redirected to `https://example.com`.

NOTE: when we open `https://www.example.com`, the site loaded well but when the URL is `www.example.com` or `https://www.example.com` it was not redirected.

We are using Ubuntu at AWS.

Answer (score 1):

To do this I would recommend editing your nginx configuration file (usually in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/you-example-config), adding return 301 as seen [here](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#server-name-if), something like:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443;
    server_name www.example.com example.com;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
    #[...ssl settings go here, certs etc....]
}
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name example.com;
    # [...ssl and main settings go here...]
}
```

This will cause all requests to return https://example.com

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined a separate server for each of the options?
See example snippet below.
Your question looks very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947030/nginx-no-www-to-www-and-www-to-no-www) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11323735/nginx-remove-www-and-respond-to-both)  which both have a lot more information that I won't copy paste here.

This link might also help
[creating-nginx-rewrite-rules](https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/)

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.example.com;
    return 301 $scheme://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    # here goes the rest of your config file
    # example 
    location / {

        rewrite ^/cp/login?$ /cp/login.php last;
        # etc etc...

    }
```

}

`$scheme` is the protocol (HTTP or HTTPS) and `$request_uri` is the full URI including arguments.