# put nginx behind aws ELB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, elastic-load-balancer

Currently my server `littlehome.kr` points to an ec2 nginx and I'm changing DNS entry so that `www.littlehome.kr` points to the ELB.

I want multiple nginx (target) behind ELB. (That's the point of having load balancer anyway.)

1. Should all of my nginx conf would use `littlehome.kr` as server_name?
2. I want `www.littlehome.kr` to be redirected to `littlehome.kr` How can I do that?

I had the following in my nginx.conf

```
server {
# http://stackoverflow.com/a/19238614/433570
  listen 80;
  server_name www.littlehome.kr;
  return 301 $scheme://littlehome.kr$request_uri;
}
```